# Struts2 spring integration error for loading index page with action class

Tags: spring, struts2, struts2-spring-plugin

```
18:23:26,988 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/strutsNew]] (MSC service thread 1-2) Exception starting filter struts2: Unable to load configuration. - action - vfs:/C:/jboss-as-web-7.0.0.Final/bin/content/strutsNew.war/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:5:37
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:431) [struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:69) [struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:51) [struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:447) [jbossweb-7.0.0.CR4.jar:7.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3245) [jbossweb-7.0.0.CR4.jar:7.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3836) [jbossweb-7.0.0.CR4.jar:7.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:70) [jboss-as-web-7.0.0.Final.jar:7.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1765)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ClearTCCLTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2291)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_45]
Caused by: Unable to load configuration. - action - vfs:/C:/jboss-as-web-7.0.0.Final/bin/content/strutsNew.war/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:5:37
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:58) [xwork-core-2.1.6.jar:]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:374) [struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:418) [struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar:]
    ... 11 more
Caused by: Action class [login] not found - action - vfs:/C:/jboss-as-web-7.0.0.Final/bin/content/strutsNew.war/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:5:37
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.verifyAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:409) [xwork-core-2.1.6.jar:]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:354) [xwork-core-2.1.6.jar:]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addPackage(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:468) [xwork-core-2.1.6.jar:]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:264) [xwork-core-2.1.6.jar:]
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:111) [struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar:]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:193) [xwork-core-2.1.6.jar:]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:55) [xwork-core-2.1.6.jar:]
    ... 13 more

18:23:26,988 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-2) Error filterStart
18:23:26,988 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-2) Context [/strutsNew] startup failed due to previous errors
18:23:26,988 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/strutsNew]] (MSC service thread 1-2) Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
18:23:26,988 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/strutsNew]] (MSC service thread 1-2) Shutting down log4j
18:23:26,988 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-2) registering web context: /strutsNew
18:23:26,988 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) Replaced deployment "strutsNew.war" with deployment "strutsNew.war"
```

please help me for this error for Struts2 and spring integration
i m using jboss server,
and using build.properties and build.xml files
web.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>StrutsNewFirststrutsInteg</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter 
    </filter-class>
  </filter>

<listener> 
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class> 
</listener> 

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

struts.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.1//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.1.dtd">
<struts>
<package name="abc" extends="struts-default">
<action name="login" class="login" >
<result name="success">welcome.jsp</result>
</action>

</package>

</struts>
```

applicationContext.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<bean id="login" class="com.cluster.action.Login">
<property name="message" value="Welcome Spring"></property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Where is the code ? web.xml, struts.xml,...

Comment: `Caused by: Action class [login] not found`, does it exist?

Comment: ya i mentioned in struts.xml

Comment: and i added al the jar in lib folder (Web-inf/lib)

Comment: "All the jar" meaning...?

Comment: What a classloader used to load classes?

Comment: i added struts2 and spring jars in lib folder

Comment: ya finaly i got answer and i try to get the answer through plugin...

Answer (score 0):

just use proper struts2-spring plugin properly as you using the jar be aware about plugins and i use(struts2-spring-plugin-2.1.6.jar). just add this to lib folder and re-build project you can get proper output, if you getting above error

thanks for all suggession.